# When runing tests in jest, node_modules imports gets undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

What's wrong with my jest configuration that I'm not able to get `node_modules` to be resolved in jest execution? They are getting undefined...

sample test file:

```
import lodash from 'lodash'

it('test', () => {
  expect(lodash.max([1,2])).toBe(2)
})
```

test (jest) output:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'max')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'max')
```

jest.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig.json')
const moduleNameMapper = require('tsconfig-paths-jest')(tsconfig)

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper,
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin').default
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/server.ts',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: process.env.RUNTIME_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
        loader: '@graphql-tools/webpack-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({})],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts","./global.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "_warmup/**/*",
    ".vscode/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was with importing CommonJS/AMD/UMD modules. I was missing `"esModuleInterop": true` in my tsconfig.json

This topic helped me: https://github.com/vercel/ms/issues/186

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using Nrwl/Nx, it defaults to SWC compilation which compiles differently than ts-jest. This resulted in undefined imports when testing where the import was not using an asterisk `import stuff from 'stuff'`. To fix, you would use `import * as stuff from 'stuff'` but then the code fails at run time.

esModuleInterop 'caused this particular case to work but others to fail. The only solution was to remove @swc/register as a dependency.